# d3js chart transition not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I cannot figure out why during the chart transitions in the attached [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/XLA5g/) the bars do not refresh properly.

If you click on "CLICK ME" a few times you will see that  when DATA1 is selected (for example) bars for x values of 13 to 19 do not appear. I have three data sets that the chart randomly picks to use in refreshing itself, each with a different number of x-values.

Can someone help me understand please. Thank you in advance!

Code:

```
var data;

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 80,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
},
width = 838 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], 0.05);

var yL = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var yR = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxisL = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yL)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10);

var yAxisR = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(yR)
    .orient("right")
    .ticks(10);

var EfficiencyLine = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis);
})
    .y(function (d) {
    return yR(d.max_efficiency);
});

var tip = d3.tip()
    .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
    .offset([-10, 0])
    .html(function (d) {
    return "<strong>Energy:</strong> <span class='tt-text'>" + d.max_energy + "</span><br /><strong>Efficiency:</strong> <span class='tt-text'>" + d.max_efficiency + "</span>";
})

var svg = d3.select("#daychart")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

var which_data = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
switch (which_data) {
    case 1:
        data = data1;
        break;
    case 2:
        data = data2;
        break;
    case 3:
        data = data3;
        break;
    default:
};

//d3.json("http://10.0.0.13/sma/sma-php/inverterdata.php?var=CDAY&id=C1200031", function (error, data) {
data.forEach(function (d) {
    d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
    d.max_efficiency = +d.max_efficiency;
});

x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.xaxis;
}));
yL.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.max_energy;
})]);

yR.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
    return d.max_efficiency;
})]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(0)")
    .attr("y", 23)
    .attr("x", 340)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "bottom")
    .text("Timeline");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-l axis")
    .call(yAxisL)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", -50)
    .attr("x", -145)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "top")
    .text("Energy - KWh");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y-r axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
    .call(yAxisR)
    .append("text")
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("x", -160)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "top")
    .text("Efficiency - KWh/KW");

svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .on('mouseover', tip.show)
    .on('mouseout', tip.hide)
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis);
})
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return yL(d.max_energy);
})
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
    return i * 10;
})
    .duration(10)
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - yL(d.max_energy);
});

svg.append("path")
    .attr("d", EfficiencyLine(data))
    .attr("class", "EfficiencyLine");

/* //Create labels
svg.selectAll("text.label")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .text(function (d) {
    if (d.max_energy == 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return parseFloat(Math.round(d.max_energy * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
    };
})
    .attr("x", function (d) {
    return x(d.xaxis) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
})
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return yL(d.max_energy) - 2;
})
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "11px")
    .attr("fill", "black");
*/
//});

//On click, update with new data            
d3.select("p").on("click", function () {

    var which_data = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1
    switch (which_data) {
        case 1:
            data = data1;
            break;
        case 2:
            data = data2;
            break;
        case 3:
            data = data3;
            break;
        default:
    };

    // Get the data again
    //      d3.json("http://10.0.0.13/sma/sma-php/inverterdata.php?var=PDAY&id=P100023", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.max_energy = +d.max_energy;
        d.max_efficiency = +d.max_efficiency;
    });

    // Scale the range of the data again 
    x.domain(data.map(function (d) {
        return d.xaxis;
    }));
    yL.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.max_energy;
    })]);
    yR.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.max_efficiency;
    })]);

    svg.select("g.x").call(xAxis);
    svg.select("g.y-l").call(yAxisL);
    svg.select("g.y-r").call(yAxisR);

    // Make the changes
    svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
    .data(data) // Update the data within.
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
        return i / data.length * 1000;
    })
        .duration(500)
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.xaxis);
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yL(d.max_energy);
    })
        .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
        .attr("height", function (d) {
        return height - yL(d.max_energy);
    });

    svg.selectAll("path.EfficiencyLine") // change the EfficiencyLine
    .data(data) // Update the data within.
    .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
        return i / data.length * 1000;
    })
        .duration(500)
        .attr("d", EfficiencyLine(data));

/*    svg.selectAll("text.label")
        .data(data)
        .transition().delay(function (d, i) {
        return i / data.length * 1000;
    })
        .duration(500)
        .text(function (d) {
        if (d.max_energy == 0) {
            return "";
        } else {
            return parseFloat(Math.round(d.max_energy * 100) / 100).toFixed(1);
        };
    })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.xaxis) + x.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
        .attr("y", function (d) {
        return yL(d.max_energy) - 2;
    })
*/
    //});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to handle the `.enter()` and `.exit()` selections in your update functions as well, as the data sets are of different size:

```
var sel = svg.selectAll(".bar") // change the bar
    .data(data);
sel.exit().remove();
sel.enter().append("rect")
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
.attr("class", "bar");

sel.transition().delay(function (d, i) {
    return i / data.length * 1000;
})...
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XLA5g/4/).

Comment: Hi Lars, you ROCK! THANK YOU! This is not the first time you have helped me. Question though, why is the line chart behind the refreshed bars? The actual page where I have the chart is at http://solarmonitoringaustralia.com.au/partner-sma-dashboard/ so you can see what I am trying to achieve. On this page I have a third line which I cannot get to refresh either... Thanks again!

Comment: This is because the new bars are appended to the end of the DOM. You can easily fix this by creating a separate `g` element to contain all the bars. I'll update the answer with the new jsfiddle link.

Comment: Hi Lars, I have made changes to my page http://solarmonitoringaustralia.com.au/partner-sma-dashboard/ but have managed to break something else. The "new bars" do not sit on the X-axis and have lost their tooltip. What have I misunderstood from your example? Thanks!

Comment: Uhh ok, that's a lot of code you have there. What in particular should I be looking at?

Comment: I have updated the code with your input, but the newly added bars do not align to X axis, and also the red / green lines are behind them (per my comment above). Also, the new bars do not show a tooltip, and lastly the green bar does not update with the data changes. you can click on "today" through to "Life" to see (the only buttons working at this stage). MANY THANKS for your help!

Comment: I do not know how to represent in JSFiddle the code with the JSON data pull, sorry! Another comment is I do see the data for the green line change in background (via console.log) but it does not flow into the chart.

Comment: The new bars are appended to the main SVG, not to the `g` that you append the other bars to. You'll need to do your selection from that `g` element -- have a look at my updated jsfiddle, which does something similar so that the new bars appear behind the line.

Comment: Hi Lars, genius! Thanks!